# Echo and backslash (bash)

Tags: bash, echo, backslash

I'm trying to make a function in my ~/.bashrc file that uses an echo command to pass its arguments through the pipeline. It works, but when I try to input a '\' character it disappears. If I type \\ (two '\') it succeeds. This heppens even with -E option...

So, how can I make the code below prints "foo\bar" instead of "foobar"?

```
func()
{
    echo -E "${@}"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `echo` who interpretes the backslash, it is the shell. It gets interpreted even before your function gets called. The correct solution is to quote the argument to the function.

```
func()
{
    echo -E "${@}"
}

func 'foo\bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you actually feed a backslash to the function; the function itself works fine, as in:
jlaiho@LT2:~$ fun() { echo -E "$@"; }
jlaiho@LT2:~$ fun 'foo\bar'
foo\bar

If, however, the backslash doesn't even reach the function, it won't be printed:
jlaiho@LT2:~$ fun foo\bar
foobar